# Filter List to the same list using Linq

Tags: linq

How can i filter the same list using a certain condition.  i know using two lists. I want to do it with the same list ..

If i have a list called lstValues Which has Name and count, i want to filter 
all the items that has count as 0. 
So i created another list

```
 lstFilterdedValues.addRange(lstValues.Where(i => i.Count > 0)));
```

this works.. But i dont want to use another new List called lstFilteredValues.

I want something like

```
lstValues =lstValues.Where(i => i.Count > 0)).Select(k=>(k));
```

But this doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ToList()` call:

```
lstValues = lstValues.Where(i => i.Count > 0).ToList();
```

It will create new list and assign it back to your `lstValues` variable.

If you don't want to create new list and reassign the variable you can use `List<T>.RemoveAll` method:

```
lstValues.RemoveAll(i => i.Count <= 0);
```

As you can see, you have to reverse the condition, because it specifies which items will be removed, not which should stay in the list.